# How to merge graphs in xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, xlsxwriter

I have two graphs,

> 1 : Line graph and
>   2 : Waterfall graph having y2 axis.

I want to merge those two graphs into a single graph having two y-axis. Is there any method to do it?[image]

Comment: XlsxWriter doesn't support Waterfall charts. For other chart types it is possible to merge them. See this example from the docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_combined.html

Comment: I hv created stacked chart and made one bar transparent to look like water flow graph.
But when i am trying to merge the line graph and stack graph, for stack graph the value is starting from negative y axis if line chart has negative value.